# Anyone know how to use Text.Regex for word boundary?

Tags: haskell

I use **Text.Regex** package right now.

I try to use subRegex for **word boundary**,

```
let r = mkRegex "\\bdog\\b"

subRegex r "mydog dog" "(\\0)"
```

output => "mydog dog"

I also try following:

```
let r = mkRegex "\\b(dog)\\b"

subRegex r "mydog dog" "(\\0)"
```

output => "mydog dog"

I try to change "mydog dog" => "mydog (dog)"

Comment: It is not clear what you want to change and how. Could you be more clear on that? Do you just need a regex to wrap a word with parenthesis?

Comment: Given string "mydog dog", I want to use subRegex to change the string to "mydog (dog)" , e.g. put bracket around my word, which is "dog" in this case

Comment: In Regex,  word is [a-zA-Z_]+ I think,

Comment: `Text.Regex` implements POSIX regular expressions only, which do not support word boundaries.  Try [regex-pcre](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre) for Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text.Regex` from the `regex-compat` package uses POSIX-compatible regular expressions, not PCRE ones.

In POSIX regular expressions, the left word boundary is `\<` and the right word boundary is `\>`:

```
ghci> let r = mkRegex "\\<dog\\>"
ghci> subRegex r "mydog dog" "(\\0)"
"mydog (dog)"
```

Comment: Actually, I use your code, the output still is  "mydog dog" on my GHCI

Comment: How do I know subRegex is from regex-compat, not from other package?

Comment: Here are the regex on my machine.

Comment: regex-base-0.93.2
regex-compat-0.95.1
regex-posix-0.95.2